# Status: The printer may not exist or is unavailable at this time

Tags: printing

Out of the blue, my print jobs for my networked printer no longer leave the "Processing" Status.

When I ping my printer IP, I get a response, so the network connection is available. And the TCP ports are open as well (see below.)

```
$ lpstat -l
RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN-54 bram            102400   Tue 31 May 2022 09:34:47 AM
    Status: The printer may not exist or is unavailable at this time.
    Alerts: job-printing
    queued for RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN
```

The printer was working fine two days ago. I power-cycled both printer and computer.

```
~$ sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd
DEBUG: Querying "RICOH\032Aficio\032SP\0323510DN\032\04075a879\041._ipp._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: Querying "RICOH\032Aficio\032SP\0323510DN\032\04075a879\041._pdl-datastream._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: Querying "RICOH\032Aficio\032SP\0323510DN\032\04075a879\041._printer._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: sent=0, count=3
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x5561e7b64290, interfaceIndex=2, protocol=1, event=0, fullName="RICOH\032Aficio\032SP\0323510DN\032\04075a879\041._ipp._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=0x5561e7b64958, rdlen=291, flags=5, context=0x5561e7b63550)
DEBUG2: query_callback: "txtvers=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "rp=ipp/port1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "note=local.".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "qtotal=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "priority=50".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "ty=RICOH Aficio SP 3510DN (75a879)".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "product=(RICOH Aficio SP 3510DN)".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "pdl=application/postscript,application/vnd.hp-PCL,application/vnd.hp-PCLXL,text/plain".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "adminurl=http://3510DN-75A879.local".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MFG=RICOH".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MDL=RICOH Aficio SP 3510DN".
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x5561e7b64290, interfaceIndex=2, protocol=0, event=0, fullName="RICOH\032Aficio\032SP\0323510DN\032\04075a879\041._ipp._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=0x5561e7b64958, rdlen=291, flags=5, context=0x5561e7b63550)
...
```

Note: the above blurb from `dnssd` repeats 3 more times, not sure why.

Also, `nmap` reports that services are available:

```
$ nmap 10.0.1.3
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-31 11:07 PDT
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.3
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
80/tcp   open  http
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp
9100/tcp open  jetdirect

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.30 seconds
```

CUPS service is running:

```
$ systemctl status cups
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-05-31 11:04:55 PDT; 21min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cups.path
             ● cups.socket
       Docs: man:cupsd(8)
   Main PID: 855 (cupsd)
     Status: "Scheduler is running..."
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 18807)
     Memory: 65.5M
        CPU: 22.756s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
             ├─ 855 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
             ├─ 901 RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN 54 bram cv_stolk.pdf 1 "HQwtrmrkShading=Shading20 Resolution=600dpi PageSize=Letter HQwtrmr>
             ├─ 902 ipp://10.0.1.3 54 bram cv_stolk.pdf 1 "HQwtrmrkShading=Shading20 Resolution=600dpi PageSize=Letter HQwtrmrkFontNam>
             ├─ 992 RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN 54 bram cv_stolk.pdf 1 "HQwtrmrkShading=Shading20 Resolution=600dpi PageSize=Letter HQwtrmr>
             ├─ 993 RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN 54 bram cv_stolk.pdf 1 "HQwtrmrkShading=Shading20 Resolution=600dpi PageSize=Letter HQwtrmr>
             ├─ 994 /bin/sh -e -c cat
             ├─ 995 cat
             ├─1831 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""
             ├─1832 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""
             └─2027 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// ""

May 31 11:04:55 deca systemd[1]: Starting CUPS Scheduler...
May 31 11:04:55 deca systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
May 31 11:09:31 deca hpfax[2807]: [2807]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
```

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

**Kernel:** Linux 5.15.0-33-generic

**Printer:** RICOH Aficio SP 3510DN

Comment: I had this same error message, but fixed it by turning the printer off and on again.

Answer (score 2):

The auto detected printer has an address with `.local` in it, and would (no longer) work.

```
ipp://3510DN-75A879.local:631/ipp/port1
```

When I add a printer, and explicitly set an IP address, I get a working printer again.

This time, the URI is:

```
socket://10.0.1.3:9100
```

The printer found via the IP is called "HP JetDirect" whatever that may mean. My printer is not HP, it is RICOH.

Printers in Ubuntu are simply confusing.